# Switch off auto-suggestions on a SearchBar

Tags: ios

I'm using a SearchBar, and after at least three characters are entered, I show a TableView list with possible words from a dictionary. The user can tap on a word in this list to select the desired word.

This works fine as long as iOS doesn't show his own suggestion (shown in blue below the input field).

Example: I type in "autof", and the TableView show me two entries (in German 1. "Auto fahren" and 2. "Autofahrer").

iOS show me the word "autofocus" in blue with a "X" to delete it.

If I select the second entry in this state, I want to search for "Autofahrer", but the delegation method tell me, the search word has changed to "autofocus". Now, before processing the TableView selection, a new search for possible words for "autofocus" is made, resulting in an empty TableView list, and after this, the prior selection with index = 1 is made. Of course, this results in a crash on an empty list!

I not want the iOS suggestions at all, only the selection from the list. How can I tell my program to not show suggestions on my SearchBar?

Answer (score 2):

Set `autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo` for a `UITextField` or `UITextView` as these both implement the [`UITextInputTraits` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits). The `UISearchBar` implements an `UITextField` for you and exposes this property.